# Is there a way to install golang on Mac OS X via Homebrew by specifying the semantic version?

Tags: macos, go, homebrew

I was trying to install a specific go version on my workstation by specifying the semantic version. What I meant by semantic versioning is the version number of the form `<major>.<minor>.<patch>`. For instance, to install go version `go1.13.4` I was trying this:

```
brew install go@1.13.4
```

No luck! It says  `Error: No available formula with the name "go@1.13.4"`

Comment: Install Go from the official website in any version you want (you want latest) and not  via brew.

Comment: You can, just not with the patch: `brew install go@1.13`. Installing a specific patch is a niche need I’m not sure Homebrew wants to support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to easily switch between and maintain multiple versions of go, I suggest using Go Version Manager (similar to nvm(node version manager) and rvm(ruby version manager))

https://github.com/moovweb/gvm

It's a great tool. I'd also suggest first installing the latest version go using the installer, then use GVM to install and use other versions (go compiler is now written in go after version 1.1 i believe)

Answer (score 0):

You can download GoLang's `binaries` and set as `GOROOT`. If you will need to change version of go, download required `binaries` and switch `GOROOT`.